# Python Crash Course project: Object has no attribute

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the project from Python Crash Course and in the middle of the project I'm getting this error and I couldn't figure it out why, I've got alien_invasion.py, settings.py and ship.py files, here they are:

This is main file which is alien_invasion.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, 
    ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    ship = Ship(screen)

    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

This is settings.py

```
class Settings():

    def __init__(self):

            self.screen_width = 1200
            self.screen_height = 600
            self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

and this one is ship.py

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        def blitme(self):
            self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

AND IT SAYS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alien_invasion.py", line 26, in <module>
    run_game()
  File "alien_invasion.py", line 22, in run_game
    ship.blitme()
AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'blitme'
```

Comment: Indentation makes blitme part of init in ship.py.

Comment: that's because your code indentation.. your function `blitme` is inside `__init__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you have the blitme function nested in the init in ship.py.  Tab that function back one in line with **init** and you'll be able to reference blitme().

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```